# How to get the same attribute from all objects in a list in one line

Tags: list, object, flutter, dart, attributes

I have a list of objects of the same class.
This class contains an attribute I want to use.

I would like to get a list of all these attributes in one line. Is this possible?

Here is a small example: I just want a list of all the colors.

It is important that I return directly a list of these attributes, without the normal forEach statement.

```
void main() {

List<Car> listOfCars = [
   Car('blue'), 
   Car('green'),
   Car('yellow'),
 ];
}

//List<String> listOfColors = listOfCars[all].color;

class Car{
  String color;
  Car(this.color);  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the map function to achieve this

```
 List<String> listOfColors = listOfCars.map((car) => car.color).toList();
  print(listOfColors);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check out this code below:

```
void main() {

   List<Car> listOfCars = [
    Car('blue'),
    Car('green'),
    Car('yellow'),
  ];
  List<String> stringList = List();

  // This is where you get the single car object and then you add it the list of string
  for (int i = 0; i < listOfCars.length; i++) {
      stringList.add(listOfCars[i].color);
    }

// this is the desired out put  i have just printed your list :
    print('This is the string length : ' + stringList.length.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < stringList.length; i++) {
      print('This is the string list :' + stringList[i]);
    }
 }

class Car {
  final String color;

  Car(this.color);
}
```

Blow is the output :

```
This is the string length : 3
This is the string list :blue
This is the string list :green
This is the string list :yellow
```